# 'object HTMLParagraphElement' first time a function is used

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code which adds a row to the table with a column of the opened tab's url and a generated salt. The problem is that on a click of a button first time through it will always say [object HTMLParagraphElement]  instead of the actual url. The subsequent times the button is hit, it will add the actual url. What might the cause?

Here is the relevant JavaScript code:

```js
document.getElementById("save").onclick = function() {
  anotherFunction()
};

function anotherFunction() {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    'active': true,
    'lastFocusedWindow': true
  }, function(tabs) {
    url = tabs[0].url;
    return url;
  });
  
  var salt = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  
  cell1.innerHTML = url;
  cell2.innerHTML = salt;

  localStorage.setItem("vOneLocalStorage", url);
  localStorage.setItem("vTwoLocalStorage", salt);

  return salt;
}
```

For the context, the code is used in a Chrome extension.

Comment: chrome.tabs.query is asynchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all of the code that depends on `chrome.tabs.query` inside of the callback:

```
function anotherFunction() {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    'active': true,
    'lastFocusedWindow': true
  }, function(tabs) {
    url = tabs[0].url;
    var salt = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  
    cell1.innerHTML = url;
    cell2.innerHTML = salt;

    localStorage.setItem("vOneLocalStorage", url);
    localStorage.setItem("vTwoLocalStorage", salt);
  });
}
```

Also, you never set the variable `URL` in the correct scope (as far as you have shared). I am assuming that it was equal to `url` (remember that Javascript is case-sensitive!). Also, you don't use the return value, so I have removed that.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you very much!